# Use Variable as Class Name in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have to start activity that makes use of some Variables as the Class Names. Is there a Solution out?

```
public void something(int position) {

        someVar = "MyActivity"+position;

        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,someVar.class));

}
```

Comment: not clear can you elaborate

Comment: Ok I am passing a Integer to the Method named something and my activity have names like `MyActivity1`, `MyActivity2` etc. So on passing the Integer valus, I want to start activities. For example _on passing integer 1_, I want to start Activity `MyActivity1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there aren't too many activities, you can always do this:

```
Class myclass;

Switch(position){

    case 1:
        myclass = Activity1.class;
        break;
    case 2:
        myclass = Activity2.class;
        break;
    case 3:
        myclass = Activity3.class;
        break;
}

startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,myclass));
```

Comment: or put them in an array

Comment: Ok its one of the solutions. But Is there no exact solutions for what I asked. Sometimes I may need to address the `string variables` like : `string`+ _position_

Comment: As @Raghunandan said before, it's not clear enough. Give us some more info and we'll try our best to help you. Plus, Why are you calling this activities by numbers instead of names?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the `class` of the Activity you are starting. You can use a `setClassName`:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(this, "MyActivity" + position);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I am on activity Help. This Crashes when I want to get to Main Activity. Am I missing something? Thank you again.  
  `Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setClassName(this, "Main");
  startActivity(i);`

Comment: you possibly need an action and/or a category

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get the class type. Just make sure you include the package name in the string.

```
public void something(int position) throws ClassNotFoundException {

  Class<?> theClass = Class.forName("com.example.Activity" + position);

  startActivity(new Intent(this, theClass));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still confused and looking for "The Solution" not the "Work-Arounds", it's very simple to pass a class reference as a variable, put into consideration that this example is derived from an Android context:
Variable is:
Class<? extends package.ClassNameHere> variableName;

Comment: Please format the code chunks with the ` sign appropriately for better understanding